# received this error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-map-gl

Im new in reactjs I am receiving this error: "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." and I am not sure how to solved it.

```
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = ''; ///add token here

export default function MapHooks(){
    const [mapping, setMapping] = useState({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        longitude: -122.45,
        latitude: 37.78,
        zoom: 14
      });

    function _onViewportChange(mapping){
        setMapping({mapping})
    }

    function _goToNYC() {
        const viewport = {
            ...mapping,
            longitude: 101.7412,
            latitude: 3.1549,
            zoom: 14,
            transitionDuration: 5000,
            transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
            transitionEasing: d3.easeCubic
        };
        setMapping({viewport}) 

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={_goToNYC()}>New York City</button>
            <MapGL
            {...mapping}
            mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10"
            onViewportChange={_onViewportChange()}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
            ></MapGL>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please help, thank you :)

Comment: Are you using useEffect?

Comment: hi there, I am not using useEffect, but if i am using it can i add in into onClick button? *sorry for my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be executing the function when assigning it to the `onClick`, you should just be passing it in like so:

```
<button onClick={_goToNYC}>New York City</button>
```

If you actually call it when you assign it, then the function will execute. In that execution you call `setMapping(...)`, which will trigger a re-render. Which will then cause that function to be executed again when the button renders, and so on -> infinite loop

Comment: React uses something called Synthetic events to achieve cross-browser event handling. Read more about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 2):

this is the latest source code. thank you :)

```
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = ''

export default function MapHooks(){
    const [mapping, setMapping] = useState({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        longitude: -122.45,
        latitude: 37.78,
        zoom: 14
      });

    function _goToNYC() {
        const viewport = {
            ...mapping,
            longitude: 101.7412,
            latitude: 3.1549,
            zoom: 14,
            transitionDuration: 5000,
            transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
            transitionEasing: d3.easeCubic
        };
        setMapping(viewport)            
    }

    return (
        <div style={{borderStyle: "solid"}}>
            <button onClick={_goToNYC}>2BF53E</button>
            <button>406C01</button>
            <MapGL
            {...mapping}
            mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10"
            onViewportChange={setMapping}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
            ></MapGL>
        </div>
    );
}
```